# Prevent thread blocking in Tomcat

Tags: multithreading, web-services, tomcat, thread-safety

I have a Java servlet that acts as a facade to other webservices deployed on the same Tomcat instance. My wrapper servlet creates **N** more threads, each which invokes a webservice, collates the response and sends it back to the client. The webservices are deployed all on the same Tomcat instance as different applications.

I am seeing thread blocking on this facade wrapper service after a few hours of deployment which brings down the Tomcat instance. All blocked threads are endpoints to this facade webservice (like **http://domain/appContext/facadeService**)

Is there a way to control such thread-blocking, due to starvation of available threads that actually do the processing? What are the best practices to prevent such deadlocks?

Comment: You need to improve on your answer rate. I could help you but I simply don't want to as you aren't bothered to accept the given answers.

Comment: For most of the questions I have raised I haven't found a definitive answer, and hence, they are still open.

Comment: Is there any dependency between the webservices? i.e could webservice1 call webservice2, for example?

Comment: The child services were mutually-exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

The common solution to this problem is to use the [Executor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) framework. You need to express your web service call as `Callable` and pass it to the executor either as it stands, or as a `Collection<Callable>` (see the Javadoc for complete list of options).

You have two choices to control the time. First is to use parameters of an appropriate method of the `Executor` class where you specify the max web service timeout. Another option is to do get the result (which is expressed as `Future<T>`) and use `.get(long, TimeUnit)` to specify the maximum amount of time you can wait for a result.

Comment: But using a timeout still doesn't resolve the cause of the underlying deadlock?

Comment: There is no limit to reasons why threads could become blocked - especially when no context is being given. For example it is easy to get to a deadlock if non-thread-safe classes are used (see question 1068190 on SO). But the general advice is to use Executor/Future as you can at least reclaim the threads which were hopelessly waiting for long amount of time.

Comment: We are already using the Executor framework for the same, though we didn't had a timeout on the threads.